# forEachFeatureAtPixel behaves differently on different features

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I am trying to add an overlay when clicking on a feature on a map. This is working perfectly fine. If there are several features I would like to have a table showing the dates of the pictures and make the different Dates clickable to show the images.

Here comes the problem: I have 2 Layers added with different images/icons but in general the same code is creating all the information for the layers. When I click on the Icon for the first layer, everything is working perfectly fine like expected. However, clicking on overlapping icons on the second layer shows only one date and thus one image.
To see my problem you can go to: https://forestwatch.lup-umwelt.de/app_development/ , open the Map-layer on the left and add "Fotos" and "Drohnenbilder" to the map. You will see a stack of Camera-Symbols on the right side, behaving like expected: without zooming a click on the stack will give you a bunch of dates.
Clicking on the Drone-image in the middle will open the overlay, show a single date that has to be clicked (which should not happen if there is only one image). So - no auto-opening and no table with images.

This is the code I use for detecting features:

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById('overlay'),
    positioning: 'bottom-left'
    });

var displayImage = function(pixel) {
    var features = [];
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature){
        features.push(feature);
    },{hitTolerance: 0});
    if (features.length === 1){
        var imag = features[0].values_.pointAttributes.Image;
        var date = features[0].values_.pointAttributes.Datum;
        overlay.setPosition(features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates); 
        var innerHTML = "<img ID=\"theImage\" src= " + imag + "><table id=\"fototable\"><tr><td><button class=\"btn\" disabled>" +  date + "</button><td><tr></table>";
        var element = overlay.getElement();
            element.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        map.addOverlay(overlay);
    }else if (features.length > 1) {
        var imag = [];
        var date = [];
        for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            imag.push(features[i].values_.pointAttributes.Image);
            date.push(features[i].values_.pointAttributes.Datum);
            overlay.setPosition(features[i].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates); 
            let innerHTMLStart = "<img ID=\"theImage\" src= \"\"><table id=\"fototable\">";
            let innerHTMLEnd = "</table>";
            let innerHTML = innerHTMLStart;
            let lastIndex = imag.length - 1;

            //loop over our items
            for(var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
                //first iteration
                if(i % 3 === 0 && i === 0) {
                innerHTML = innerHTML + "<tr>";
                //modulo 3 but not first iteration
                } else if(i % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
                innerHTML = innerHTML + "</tr><tr>";
                }

                 //add cells to the table
                innerHTML = innerHTML + "<td><button class=\"btn\" data-img=" + imag[i] + " onclick=\"showImage(this);\">" +  date[i] + "</button></td>";
                if(i === lastIndex) {

                //last iteration? how many <td>?
                //always finish with 3 cells
                if((i+1) % 3 === 0) {
                    innerHTML = innerHTML + "</tr>";
                } else if((i+1) % 2 === 0) {
                innerHTML = innerHTML + "<td></td></tr>";
                } else {
                innerHTML = innerHTML + "<td></td></tr>";
                }
                }
                }

                innerHTML = innerHTML + innerHTMLEnd;

            var element = overlay.getElement();
            element.innerHTML=innerHTML        
            ;
            map.addOverlay(overlay);
            }
    } else{
        var element = overlay.getElement();
        element.innerHTML = null;
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);

        
    } 
};


map.on('click', function(event) {
    var pixel = event.pixel;
    displayImage(pixel);
    });
```

And here is the code of creating the layers (same code for both just different variable-names):

```
var FotoSource = new ol.source.Vector();

$.getJSON('config/Fotos.json', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
     var newMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([this.Longitude,this.Latitude]),
            pointAttributes: {'Datum': this.Datum, 'Image':this.Name}
       
        });
    
        FotoSource.addFeature(newMarker);
        });
    });


var FotoStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'images/camera2.png',
    class: "Fotoicon"
})
});
```

I am adding them as new ol.layer.Vector with Fotosource as source.

Comment: It shows a single date but when you zoom in you can see there are multiple images taken on the same date.  Clicking on those works as expected.

Comment: @Mike Yeah I know there are multiple, but I expect the same behavior for the Drone-Imagery as for the Camera-Images. If I am zoomed out and they overlap there should be multiple dates and thus multiple images. Even if there are multiple Images on the same day for the Camera it shows the same date multiple times

Comment: I think it is when all the dates are the same.  You should end the first for loop before starting the second, or use a different variable to index the second loop.

Comment: Changing the 2nd loop to j instead of i solved the problem! Please feel free to add this Comment as an answer so i can accept it.